# cell.Offset Object needed

Tags: vba, excel, offset

This loop worked perfectly with excel solver, but due to the fact the solver has restrictions of 200 variables I am trying a different solver that is called "WhatsBest" now. When I start the simulation now, it tells me that an object is needed and when I want to debug it, it shows me, that it is in the cell.offset line. Is there anything more I have to consider with this code?

```
Sub MakroBisect()
Dim StartTime As Date
Dim EndTime As Date


StartTime = Timer

    wbAdjust "$P$4:$BC$8"
    wbBest "C32", "Minimize"
    wbConstraint "P9:BB9", "=", "P11:BB11", "P10:BB10"
    wbConstraint "J3:J7", ">=", "L3:L7", "K3:K7"
    WBBIN "Plantusage", "BC4:BC8"
    wbSolve

Range("M3:M7").ClearContents
Range("H27") = 1000
Range("H28") = 100000


Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("D3:D7")

For Each cell In rng

    Do
    If cell.Offset(1, 51).Value = 1 Then

        Range("H27") = cell.Value

    Else
        Range("H28") = cell.Value

    End If

        cell.Value = Range("H29").Value

        wbAdjust "$P$4:$BC$8"
        wbBest "C32", "Minimize"
        wbConstraint "P9:BB9", "=", "P11:BB11", "P10:BB10"
        wbConstraint "J3:J7", ">=", "L3:L7", "K3:K7"
        WBBIN "Plantusage", "BC4:BC8"
        wbSolve

    Loop Until Range("H31") = 1

    Range("H27").Value = 0
    Range("H28").Value = 100000

    'Copying cell Value, when Solver solution switched in certain cell depending if it before was 1 or 0
    cell.Copy cell.Offset(, 9)
    'Copying start value back into cell after solver loop
    cell.Offset(, -1).Copy cell

        wbAdjust "$P$4:$BC$8"
        wbBest "C32", "Minimize"
        wbConstraint "P9:BB9", "=", "P11:BB11", "P10:BB10"
        wbConstraint "J3:J7", ">=", "L3:L7", "K3:K7"
        WBBIN "Plantusage", "BC4:BC8"
        wbSolve

Next cell


EndTime = Timer
Range("H8").Value = Format(EndTime - StartTime, "0.0")


End Sub
```

The point I don't understand, that when using Excel solver there is no problem with the object.

Comment: I think `cell` is one of those protected words that can cause code issues when you use it as a variable.  Most code I've seen uses `cel` in that case.

Comment: `cell.offset` appears in many places. Which one?

Comment: @Chrismas007 meh. the local variable simply "hides" the global-scope object.. which isn't a problem *if the global-scope object isn't accessed*. `Range` and `Cell` calls should be qualified with a worksheet object, to remove ambiguities and implicit reliance on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @A.S.H - isn't it just the variable used in the loop? 'Cells' is no doubt protected but I would have thought 'cell' is fine (not that I would use it).

Comment: @SJR that comment belongs to Christmas007. AFAIK, `cell` is not a reserved keyword, although I somehow agree with the comment, it is good practice to use `cel` instead.

Comment: @A.S.H - apologies for confusion, My first point was in answer to your question "which one?".

Comment: Ah, right, it's `Cells`, not `Cell`. I always get those auto-completed out of IntelliSense, that's why I'm never sure exactly how it's spelled out!

Comment: Thanks for that many answers :) But I am sorry but I didn't really get the point? I tried to change it from cell to cells, but that did not word...when I want to debug it tells me that the problem is in that line If cell.Offset(1, 51).Value = 1 Then ... @MatsMug what do you exactly mean how I should qualify range and cell?

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: I changed Cell to Cells now, but this did not change anything...error message is error 1004 - "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Comment: Sees that you misunderstood the guys' comments above. They were not asking you to change `cell` into `cells`, not at all, this would make things worse. Eventually they recommended `cel` intead of `cell` (but not necessary anyway). Finally, the error message you pointed out is different than the one you gave in the OP (*an object is needed*), which makes your problem very hard to follow.

Comment: So I try to explain my problem again: The code is still the same as above...but everytime I start my simulation I get the Error Code 1004 - "Application-defined or Object-defined error" as explained above...when I debug, it goes to the line If cell.Offset(1, 51).Value = 1. So what I don't understand is: Do I need to define anything in this line? Or can I use cell.offset like I did in my code?